# How to retrieve an images from PHp myadim database and display in android list view?

Tags: php, android, mysql

How to retrieve an images from PHP my admin database and display in android list view?
I have the following script to retrieve the name and id. But i don't know how to retrieve the image as well.
How do i will retrieve image by using the same query?

```
    <?php

/*
Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.php");

//initial query
$query = "Select * FROM channels";

//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();
        $post["channelname"] = $row["channelname"];
        $post["channelid"]    = $row["channelid"];



        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);


} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Channel Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will that work, I have edited this after your comment

```
    <?php

/*
Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.php");

//initial query
$query = "Select * FROM channels";

//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();
        $post["channelname"] = $row["channelname"];
        $post["channelid"]    = $row["channelid"];
        $post["image"]    = $row["content"];



        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);


} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Channel Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```

Comment: The name of my field of image is "contents" so i changed my script but its not working. I want you to please edit my script to read all the data in json format –

Comment: Can you please add specific issues

Comment: Yes i just have to get the image from server and to display in the list view in android

Comment: Can you add the following to the question, database structure, android code?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, each $row array will have extra fields.  One of these might be a URL or path to the images;  you can use

```
print_r($row)
```

or

`var_dump($row)`

in the block below

```
foreach ($rows as $row) { ... }
```

to see what other data is held within those arrays.

Finally, you should include that data in your $response array.

Comment: The name of my field of image is "contents" so i changed my script but its not working. I want you to please edit my script to read all the data in json format

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing you have following columns in your table

1) ID
2) Name
3) Image

If images are stored in Database then type of `image` field would be `blob`

Now here is the code to fetch the image from database

```
<?php
$host="your_hostname";
$user="your_databaseuser";
$pass="your_database_password";
$db="database_name_to_use";

// just so we know it is broken
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 // some basic sanity checks
 if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
     //connect to the db
     $link = mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass")
     or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

     // select our database
     mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());

     // get the image from the db
     $sql = "SELECT image FROM test_image WHERE id=" .$_GET['id'] . ";";

     // the result of the query
     $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());

?>
```

The image is fetched from database and is in `$result`, now it is displayed in Html by setting content type as follow

```
<?php
     // set the header for the image
     header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
     echo mysql_result($result, 0);

     // close the db link
     mysql_close($link);
 }
 else {
     echo 'Please use a real id number';
 }
```

?>

You can set the result variable to post varialble to bind in your json array to use it further

Comment: The name of my field of image is "contents" so i changed my script but its not working. I want you to please edit my script to read all the data in json format

Comment: after `json_encode()` we need to put `exit()` that i have added please try now

Comment: can you please edit my script with the given details because i am new to this so i m not able to properly do this. Thanks